# How does the Google country search filter change results?

Tags: google-search

E.g. If I search for a result in www.google.co.uk, then afterwards I click "Search Tools" and select "Country: UK" from the "Any Country" dropdown, the results will change...

But how does country UK change things when I'm already using google.co.uk? Why do both exist?

I'm confused :/

Answer (score 2):

If you do a search, Google will show all sites which are relevant, regardless of their location. If you decide to filter by 'Country: UK'  then it will mainly show the sites which are geo-targeted to the UK.

Comment: Thanks, but there must be more to it. If I do a search for "cars" on google.co.uk and google.com.au, for example - WITHOUT utilising the country select - then the results are still geotargeted. So it seems there must be two layers of geotargeting going on, and I just don't understand how they're distinguished...

Comment: Hi there. Any chance you could speak to this? I would definitely mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: (I dont think searching with broad keyword like cars will show much for any sort of investigation. Try a query which could be international and the difference is more relevant.) You are right in saying the results are still geo-targeted without the country filter, though without the country filter you see everything relevant for .co.uk regardless of where it is geo-located and with the country filter you see everything for .co.uk and which is geo-targeted to .co.uk

Comment: OK, thanks. That would seem to suggest that the non-country filter search would return more "UK relevant" results since it is more inclusive, but I suppose the opposite is in fact true, because those that have been geotargeted are just that - even MORE relevant than those that haven't?

Answer (score 0):

They check the language of your browser if I'm correct. So that means they conclude that you are UK based on your browser's language (en_UK), maybe combined with the domain extention (but I dont believe the latter has much to do with it).

If you manualy go to another countries domain, it sees that you are not using the countries default version, so you must have a reason, so they show you the result in that language.

Same goes for the manual overwrite via the 'any country'.

Answer (score -3):

The dropdown option "Any Country" shows you "Google.com" results. It will get you from Google.co.uk to Google.com results.

Comment: I am already in co.uk, then I click the dropdown and it takes me to Country:UK, so that cannot be true.